# Modern authoritive textbook for morpheme analyses

Tags: reference-request, morphemes, lexemes

I have been reading several books dealing with morpheme/semanteme, etc...But some of them are a few decades old and don't deal exclusively with the subject in the scope of Lexicology. So I would like to ask for references to contemporary books that are currently considered an authoritative reference and generally consensual.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “exclusively dealing with the subject in the scope of lexicology”?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of books that you have read so far?